# JavaFX-8 Show day in DatePicker's editor

Tags: date, datepicker, javafx-8

Is there an easy way to show the day in the editor field of DatePicker?

Like "Wednessday, 26.11.2014" instead of only "26.11.2014"?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the default formatter of the date picker. For that there's a proper formatter: `DateTimeFormatter`. Read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

For your request, we need this pattern:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, d.MM.uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

And now, we can set our custom `LocalDate` converter:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    DatePicker datePicker=new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    datePicker.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDate object) {
            return object.format(formatter);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
            return LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane(datePicker);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note the formatter works in two ways: when picking a date from the popup, it will format it with `toString()` to show it on the editor field, and when you edit this field to enter a new local date, it will try to parse it to a valid `LocalDate` with `fromString()`. If it's not valid it will restore the last valid date.